# VSCode launches wsl.exe processes which are not terminated after VSCode is closed

Tags: visual-studio-code

Lately, after I have been using VSCode for some time, opening and closing it repeatedly, I was surprised to see, in Process Explorer, a lot of wsl.exe processes. As it looks, 4 or 5 processes were started by VSCode each time I opened it, but were not terminating when I was closing VSCode, so I ended up with a lot of them (there are only 5 in the image, but actually there were several dozens).

[image]

I think this has something to do with the following dialog box I see (almost?) every time I open VSCode

[image]

(which I was just closing since I am not interested to install these extensions).

Does someone know how to disable the launching of these processes? I had a Docker extension which I uninstalled, but this behavior persists.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so the culprit is not this something which launches the dialog box (I still see it), but it appears to be the following setting (when checked)

[image]

After unchecking it, I don't see now any wsl.exe processes launched when I start VSCode.